# A better PHP switch command

Tags: php

In pick basic there is a case command which functions similar to the switch command basically doing nested if then else commands.  The code is like this:

`begin case
      case a=4;do something
      case b=5 or c=6;do something
      case y=x and f=z;do something
      case 1;do something
     end case`

if any of the conditions are true, it falls into that case.  I know PHP has the switch command, but that is limited to the value of one variable.  Is there a way to code the above in PHP or javascript for that matter without a bunch of if then else commands similar to the above?

Comment: well you can just use an `else if`. will work too, just more characters to type with `else if (7) case (4)`

Comment: It may not be the best use of it, but you _could_ switch on `true`, then your cases would be similar to `case $a == 4: yadda(); yadda(); break;`, `case $b == 5 || $c == 6: break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to use `if`/`else`, then `switch (true)` *can* work:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($a === 4):
        doSomething();
        break;
    case ($b === 5 || $c === 6):
        doSomething();
        break;
    case ($y === $x || $f === $z):
        doSomething();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

However, it is less typing, and it makes your code more readable, if you simply use `if`/`else` instead, just as Shomz suggested. I really wouldn't recommend using `switch (true)`.

Comment: Great idea! I've never seen it before. +1

Comment: It also introduces the thought that cases can evaluate to true/false; I had seen a production system bug recently where the switch statement was a non-boolean variable, but the cases were written to evaluate as booleans. It makes it simpler if switch(true) and boolean cases were just not allowed in the codebase (as a style rule)

Comment: I really like this solution.  Very readable and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `case` with `else if` is only 3 bytes longer, I don't see the big deal because that is exactly what the `if/else` is for. Switches are used for single variables, as you said.

Your `do something` could also include a result variable or a flag that will be set if any of the conditions are met.

So this:

```
begin case
  case a=4;do something
  case b=5 or c=6;do something
  case y=x and f=z;do something
  case 1;do something
 end case
```

could be:

```
  var case = false;
  if (a==4) {dosomething(); case = true}
  else if (b==5 || c==6) {dosomething(); case = true}
  else if (y==z || f==z) {dosomething(); case = true}
  else if (1) {dosomething(); case = true} // supposedly the default case?
```